# THREE.js : Look where you are going

Tags: javascript, three.js

If I am moving an object with code like

```
dx = [not important];
dy = [not important];
dz = [not important];
d = new THREE.Vector3(dx,dy,dz);
mesh.postion.add(d);
```

How do I make my mesh look where it's going? I've tried

```
mesh.lookAt(d); // fails
mesh.lookAt(copyOfMeshPosition.add(d)) // fails
```

and setting mesh.up to (1,0,0), (0,1,0), and (0,0,1).

Comment: If it matters my mesh is added to an Object3D, but that object is left at 0,0,0

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the lookAt method takes a coordinate in **world** space, not local space.

If you wish an object at (3, 5, 0) to look in the direction of (dx, dy, dz), you would need to look at a point in that direction in **world** coordinates.

i.e. The point (3, 5, 0) + (dx, dy, dz)

e.g.

```
d = new THREE.Vector3(dx, dy, dz);
mesh.postion.add(d);
mesh.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3().addVectors(mesh.position, d));
```

Comment: They were orient in relation to there heading -- everything heading in the same direction points the same wrong way. I'm just going to suck it up and actually get my head around quaterion.